# window.navigator properties return null on iPad with MDM-restrictions

Tags: vue.js, ipad, safari, mdm, navigator

I am trying to detect if a client is an iPad, and to do that I'm trying to use `window.navigator.platform` and `window.navigator.maxTouchPoints`.

I'm trying to do this from Vue, by setting it as a computed property.

One device I have to test this with is an MDM-device, an iPad running the latest iOS and using Safari as the browser.

This is my computed property:

```js
// ...
computed: {
    isIpad() {
        return navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
    }
}
```

And this is the view:

```html
<div class="feature">
    <div v-if="isIpad" class="feature-desktop">This feature is only available on desktops.</div>
</div>
```

In my vue-inspector on MacOS/Firefox the computed property is correct, returning `false` as expected. When I try to emulate an iPad through Firefox, it returns `true`, as expected. However, if I open the page using Safari on my MDM-enabled iPad, this property returns `false`.

Sadly, I cannot connect with developer tools as the iPad is locked down, but I can manually put javascript on the page to print out the result of both `navigator.platform` and `navigator.maxTouchPoints`, and they return the expected `MacIntel` platform and `5` touch points.

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = navigator.platform + ' ' + navigator.maxTouchPoints; // Prints MacIntel and 5
</script>
```

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing? I've yet to attempt setting a `data`-property with `mounted()`.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with using a computed property (rather than a property on `data`). Have you tried checking if `navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2`? I have seen that suggested as a solution elsewhere.

Comment: I think it was a timing issue, if anything. Could be something specific to Safari. I added a `mounted` event handler to set a data property, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `mounted` event handler to set a `data`-property solved my problem.